# Downgrading a package to older versions on Kali

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, wpa-supplicant

From bug reports from various forums i concluded that downgrading wpa supplicant might be a solution for my connection problem. I need to downgrade the wpasupplicant (2.10 is the current version) to be able to connect my school network. I am using Kali Linux right now, and don't know how to downgrade wpasupplicant to some older version like 2.9.

https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/cannot-connect-to-wifi-network-after-wpa-supplicant-upgrade/23207/18

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/73495?project=1&order=dateopened&sort=desc

I have tried
`sudo apt install --allow-downgrades wpasupplicant=2:2.10-2`

But get an error
`E: Version '2:2.10-2' for 'wpasupplicant' was not found`

Also in another question about this problem(below link) it is said to add the required repositories to downgrade. But again i need help with that part.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wi-fi-connection-to-a-corporate-network

For different versions of wpasupplicant i found

https://repology.org/project/wpa-supplicant/versions
But i don't know how to downgrade using these repos.

Comment: "I need to downgrade the wpasupplicant" - why? What leads to this conclusion? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Updated the question so it might be more clear.

Comment: `apt-cache madison <package name>` to list available versions in the repo. Why do you pass `2:2.10-2` if you want to downgrade to 2.9?

Comment: It is also a valid version as the bugreports say. Also @Panki that command has an output of just 2:2.10-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have lots of problems with wpa_supplicant v2.10 - for me I can't create a wifi hotspot which is usable at all. I've the same issue on ubuntu, so here is the answer for Kali Linux (confirmed working):

```bash
# add in old (sadly unsigned) source list
deb http://old.kali.org/kali 2021.1 main contrib non-free

# since the source list doesn't include a .gpg file, we need to manually allow it
apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories

# match the version of wpasupplicant that was in the old repo
sudo apt --allow-downgrades install wpasupplicant=2:2.9.0-17

# prevent the package from being upgraded
sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant

# check is working with
wpa_supplicant -v

# wpa_supplicant v2.9
# Copyright (c) 2003-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

(All the above is inspired by a [blog post with instructions for ubuntu](https://blog.incompetent.me/2023/02/ubuntu-2204-hotspot-stops-working.html))